# Error with String.format()

Tags: java, string, format

Below is simple code, I got `java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException` whenever `i == 0`.

```
java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();
int i = r.nextInt(2);
String s = String.format(
    String.format("%s", i == 0 ? "%d" : "%f"),
    i == 0 ? r.nextInt() : r.nextFloat());
System.out.println(s);
```

The stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Float
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4011)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2725)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2677)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2449)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2383)
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2781)
    at hb.java.test.App.testCompiler(App.java:17)
    at hb.java.test.App.main(App.java:10)
```

Could someone please explain if I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a weird one.  Looks like the second conditional (i == 0 ? r.nextInt() : r.nextFloat()) is casting both to Float because of the second parameter.  Never seen this before.

Here's something that works:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();
        int i = r.nextInt(2);
        String s;
        if(i == 0){
            s = String.format("%d", r.nextInt());
        }
        else{
            s = String.format("%f", r.nextFloat());
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Comment: +1 Great catch! It's actually handling this properly according to the spec for the conditional operator (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.25)

Comment: @John, sorry for deleted comment, I remember that I accepted yours first, then Banthar's  :-)

Answer (score 2):

`i == 0 ? r.nextInt() : r.nextFloat()` has the type float. `?:` operator cannot return both `int` and `float`.

Comment: Thanks Banthar, I could not accept two answers. But yours is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
final String s;
if ( i == 0 )
{
    s = String.format("%d", r.nextInt( ));
}
else
{
    s = String.format("%f", r.nextFloat( ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander. But I need to understand why the code is wrong. I got it  :-)

Answer (score 0):

In String.format the first parameter is the format but in your example above you have the initial %s as the first parameter then %d or %f as the object to substituted for

You need to do something like this:

```
String s = String.format(i == 0 ? "%d" : "%f", i == 0 ? r.nextInt() : r.nextFloat());
```

Comment: It still raises the same exception. Because the operator `?:` can only return one type (or `int`, or `float`), as the answers  :-)